# C# Convert.FromBase64String giving empty byte[] with valid string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I've got a bit of a mind boggler.
I have a particular little line of code, that converts a base64 string back to a byte[]. On my development pc it works without issues, but when deployed to our app server, the resulting byte array is always empty, and I can't figure out why.

I'm hoping some of you geniuses out there might know the answer?

Here's the simple one line of code:

```
byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIQ==");
```

Some context, the app that this is from is an asp.net core 2.1 web API project. The app server OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.
I have the .net core 2.1.4 runtime/hosting bundle installed.
The base64 string sample was created in a JavaScript application and is a plain text file that contains "Hello World!!"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That won't fail, something else is going on. Is that literally the exact code or is the string derived dynamically? What are you using to determine the array is empty?

Comment: Hi Crowcoder, that string is derived dynamically from a .txt file with "Hello Wold!!" in it, but I even tried it just as you see it there and it still gives me an empty byte array. I first noticed that the array was empty because I have code in a try...catch that tries to create a MemoryStream with the byte[], I then added code to the catch to log the length of the byte array and some other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out I was being a real idiot, lol. I was writing the byte[] in a log, which gave me System.byte[]. For some reason I convinced myself this meant the array was empty. To support my delusion, I was getting an error on a line that creates a memory stream from the byte[]. This morning while bashing my head on it, I realized the error I'm getting is a NullReferenceException, which does not make sense for an empty array.

Long story short, the error was not what I though it was, my apologies for wasting anyone's time.

At least I have a new lead to go on to solve my error now.
Thanks for everyone that tried/wanted to help!

Comment: Of course, something like `string.Join(", ", fileBytes)` will write the contents of the array. Will give the empty string if the array is empty, and will throw an exception if `fileBytes == null` (there is no array).